# How to knit to PDF in R

Tags: pdf, knitr

I do not understand why I am getting this error when I am trying to knit to pdf. I was able to knit to pdf in a previous assignment, so I do not understand what the problem is with this one.

```
Output file: Edith_HW2.knit.md

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̣ (U+0323)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

Try other LaTeX engines instead (e.g., xelatex) if you are using pdflatex. For R Markdown users, see https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html
Error: Failed to compile Edith_HW2.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Edith_HW2.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

Comment: Seems like your document contains the unicode character ` ̣` (U+0323) which LaTeX cannot handle. Try replacing it with `\d{}`.

Comment: How do I identify the character that is "unicode"? where do I need to place "\d{}" Thank you